# Cockpit CMS won't be served by Apache after installation (404 error)

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to get Cockpit CMS (https://getcockpit.com/documentation) running on an Ubuntu 16.04 server. The documentation is limited. I've placed the cockpit folder inside my Apache Document root at `/var/www/html/root/cms`.

The installation page found at `website.com/cms/install` worked. This page now redirects to `website.com/cms/auth/login` which can't be found (404 error). `website.com/cms` also redirects to `/cms/auth/login`.

The directory `/var/www/html/root/cms/auth/login` doesn't exist (same as local). Everything works on local environment using MAMP, using the same directory structure.

Apache log has the following error, but I don't think it's related:

`server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

I've tried configuring Apache and giving `/cms/` an Alias pointing to the directory. I also changed permissions on the `/var/www/html/root/cms/` directory so that all files are readable.

I've tried changing the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html2/`. In this directory is nothing but the `cms` folder. This hasn't made a difference, and it still errors our with a 404 when requesting `website.com/cms/auth/login`

I don't think it's a dependency issue. Php version is 7.0. PDO + SQLite is installed. php7.0-gd is installed. mod_rewrite is also enabled.

Here is my sites-enabled config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect / https://website.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/root
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info  SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/website.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /alternate/ "/var/www/html/alternate/"
    <Directory "/var/www/html/alternate/">
    </Directory>
    Alias /root/ "/var/www/html/root/"
        <Directory "/var/www/html/root/">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: This shouldn't be hard. Remove your `Alias`es, remove the 2 empty `Directory` blocks. Add a `ServerName`.  Point the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/html/root/cms` (the directory where `README.md` is).  Restart Apache.  Make sure your `storage` directory is writable.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Thank you very much for the reply. I've done all that, yet the error persists. What else could be the cause?

Comment: I've added an answer with one other key step - did that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`install/index.php` really exists on disk, so as long as Apache and PHP are working you will be able to reach that file without any special server configuration.  That's how you you got there OK.

However once installed, Cockpit relies on the redirect rules specified in `.htaccess` to route URLs like `auth/login`, which *don't* exist on disk, to the appropriate real file for handling.  If this is failing, it means the rewrite rules aren't working, and you need to set that up.

First, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled.  On Ubuntu you should be able to do that like so:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Next, you need to make sure `.htaccess` file processing is enabled - if it isn't, `.htaccess` files (like the one in the Cockpit directory) are simply ignored.  Add the following section to the `VirtualHost` block of your virtual host config (probably something like `/etc/apache2/sites-available/website.conf`):

```
# The Directory should be where Cockpit's README.md is
<Directory "/var/www/html/root/cms"> 
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Next, as discussed in the comments, remove the `Alias`es and empty `Directory` blocks you have in your virtual host config, they're not required and just confuse things.  Here's the final config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect / https://website.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    # Add your real, fully-qualified servername
    ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    # The Directory should be where Cockpit's README.md is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/root/cms

    # The Directory should be where Cockpit's README.md is
    <Directory "/var/www/html/root/cms"> 
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/website.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/intermediate.crt
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache for these changes to take effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: By adding `AllowOverride All` to the directory tag, my problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cockpit CMS Requirements:

PHP >= 5.5
PDO + SQLite (or MongoDB)
GD extension
mod_rewrite enabled (on apache) !!IMPORTANT!!
```

Fix it, you can in console:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I don't think it's a dependency issue. Php version is 7.0. PDO + SQLite is installed. php7.0-gd is installed. mod_rewrite is also enabled.

Comment: @matthewninja can you show apache sites-enabled config file?

Comment: Vasya Zhuryk I've updated my post with the sites-enabled file. I've also updated the paths. I know that the config looks weird. I've also tried having the cms in the `html` folder and using `html` as the base directory. It hasn't made a difference.